# What does the DC current input to a PWM controller at partial duty cycle look like?

Tags: power-supply, pwm

I have a system where power output to a resistive heat element is throttled by a PWM controller. The PWM controller is powered by a 7 volt DC power supply. Will the input current to the PWM controller be a constant DC current, or will it fluctuate along with the PWM signal? I imagine at full duty cycle, the current input will be a constant DC current. I am mainly concerned with whether a fuse between the power supply and the PWM controller will successfully blow, even at partial duty cycle as I imagine a peak current of ten amps is needed to blow this fuse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be current ripple on the input of the PWM controller, at the PWM frequency.

How much ripple (around the average input current) depends largely on the local input capacitance of the PWM controller.

If the fuse is there for overload or short circuit protection, it should be easily blow, but it may be undersized since at 100% duty cycle your load current is 8.75A.

Comment: Most fuses will indefinitely carry the rated current (10A), and "must open" current is typically about 130% of that value, or 13.5A, and may take as long as an hour to blow. That is based on RMS value. Temperature and age may change this characteristic. Instantaneous operation may be as high as 8x to 15x, and may still take 10-20 mSec. There are also some very fast semiconductor fuses, as well as slow-blow and current limiting types.

Comment: @PStechPaul True- Though tolerances on the resistance of the heat element and the supply voltage are unknown, and with temperature that could push the current uncomfortably close to where the fuse could be a weak link. So needs some analysis to be sure the fuse isn't undersized.

Comment: If you really want to protect a sensitive and perhaps expensive PWM controller from an overload, you would need an electronic current limiter, as well as perhaps a crowbar circuit to provide a reliable short circuit that will blow the fuse or trip a circuit breaker. I agree that the 10A fuse might be a bit marginal, but should be OK, especially if PWM will usually be less than 100%. The current peaks of the PWM can be much higher than 10A, but a very large capacitive load could be a problem.